# Decompress NAND dump (custom LZ77/LZSS?)

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, file-format

I'm trying to to reverse engineer a very old STB (it was in service between 2005 and 2014). I successfully dumped the NAND of the box but I'm struggling with the compression used.

Here is an extract of the NAND dump which contains the NT loader (it's not being actually used, they use a modified FAT filesystem on the harddrive so guess it was easier to modify something existing)

```
003E9C80  C3 4E 54 4C  44 52 06 A0   3C 6E E2 98  AC C5 20 00   .NTLDR..<n.... .
003E9C90  60 0D 0A 52  65 6D 6F 76   65 20 64 69  73 6B 73 20   `..Remove disks
003E9CA0  6F 72 4C 74  68 65 20 8F   6D 65 32 61  2E FF 6B 44   orLthe .me2a..kD
003E9CB0  A1 51 20 E9  72 23 94 09   50 72 65 73  4C 90 61 6E   .Q .r#..PresL.an
003E9CC0  79 20 6B 65  47 74 6F 20   9A 09 74 61  72 74 23 6B   y keGto ..tart#k
003E9CD0  83 AC CB D8  07 53 B9 1F   74 11 64 A1  FF 07 3D FC   .....S..t.d...=.
```

On the actual harddrive the following can be found:

```
00000170  4E 54 4C 44  52 20 20 20   20 20 20 00  00 00 00 00   NTLDR      .....
00000180  55 00 00 00  00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00   U...............
00000190  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00   ................
000001A0  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00  0D 0A 52 65   ..............Re
000001B0  6D 6F 76 65  20 64 69 73   6B 73 20 6F  72 20 6F 74   move disks or ot
000001C0  68 65 72 20  6D 65 64 69   61 2E FF 0D  0A 44 69 73   her media....Dis
000001D0  6B 20 65 72  72 6F 72 FF   0D 0A 50 72  65 73 73 20   k error...Press 
000001E0  61 6E 79 20  6B 65 79 20   74 6F 20 72  65 73 74 61   any key to resta
000001F0  72 74 0D 0A  00 00 00 00   00 AC CB D8  00 00 55 AA   rt............U.
```

Now I've been reading a lot lately on all kinds of compression and I've been trying really hard to get my head around the compression used but just can't figure it out. It looks like a LZ77 or LZSS compression but I just can't figure out how the length/offsets are calculated.

For example on the 3rd line you have "me2a" which should be decompressed to "media" but there is only a single byte used (0x32) that should contain both the marker bit(s), offset and length. I presume it's referring to the "di" from "disks" in the line above, but as stated, I just can't figure it out (yet).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try analyzing the fimrware update binary (if you found one)? presumably it contains the code which decompresses data while writing it to disk.

Comment: Unfortunately not, FW upgrade(s) are not available, they were distributed over the DVB-C signal at the time and I didn't had the required hardware to make DVB-C captures.

Comment: Did you try to analyze the dumped NAND with binwalk?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but due to the compression binwalk does not find anything useful. Just a few zlib streams which are part of PNG images.

Comment: Your interpretation of the NAND extract you are showing is possibly not quite correct. The first C3 in the compressed part belongs to the clear text. The bytes seem to be the appr. last third of a fat32 master boot record. You may see the whole thing e.g. [here](http://vsprog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/vsf/tool/fakefat32/fakefat32.c) or [here](https://code.google.com/p/fatftp/source/browse/FB.c). Maybe you have the compressed first part as well which may give further hints on the compression algo.